# How can I make my windows partition functional again.l after shrinking volume with gparted

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, gparted

I tried to shrink my windows partition, although I had over 100GB of space, it only allowed me to shrink 20GB. So I tried using gparted from my Linux partition. Now my windows partition is very very slow.. Please is there a way I can fix it?

## Update

I ran chkdsk, windows disk utility. I think it helped in solving my problem. I also defragmented my drive.

Comment: @Ramhound I read somewhere that the reason that windows didn't allow me to shrink the partition was because of some system files written at the end of the disk volume. I think gparted forcefully shrunk the partition and corrupted the partition.

Comment: @Ramhound the wifi issue was because I turned of wireless in my Linux partition. Thanks for responding.

Comment: You should update your question to remove the problem about the WiFi in that case.

Comment: Restore from the backup.